# Set default height in Chrome BrowserAction Popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-action

I use following code to open a chrome browser action popup. I have specified min-width & min-height to html & body element, but it doesn't seem to work, as I can see a small white box when I click on icon & then my content & styles get applied. I am trying to set default dimensions so there shouldn't be a small white box at first at all!

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
  popup: 'index.html',
})
```

In my css:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This is a bug in Chrome, already reported in https://crbug.com/754606. They claim it's too hard to fix.

Answer (score -2):

Set height:100vh
If not height it should take height 100%.